# Debug Tomcat - Intellij Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java application that reads an XML message off a JMS queue. My app then stores the message in a database table. I want to debug the processing of this message, but am unable to.

I have built my app, and deployed it in Tomcat in debug mode. I have set my break point. I want my debugger to fire when my app processes my message.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Intellij? I am getting 2 errors when I try this:

Artifact app-web:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

1. "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE Disconnected from server"

I have checked and JAVA_HOME is set to my JDK.

2. Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably forget to add those properties:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${machine_addr} 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

[image]